# Angular 7 - Can we remove Port number

Tags: angularjs, angular

I am using Angular with ASP.Net Web application. When i am using `ng build` App build and run on URL without port number. But if i run app using `ng serve` its open with a port number.

i know that i can change port number and host name on `angular.json` file,

```
"serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "ng-app:build",
            "port": 4200,
            "host": "myapp.withAspweb.local"

      },
```

Is that possible to remove port number from URL.

```
ng server - myapp.withAspweb.local:4200
ng build - myapp.withAspweb.local
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as "no port". The default http port is 80, so just try

```
"port": 80
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always configure the port to be `80` in your `angular.json`-file, as you already mention.

In regards to changing your hostname, I'd suggest you set it to `0.0.0.0` (any incoming host) and modify your `hosts` file (located in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`) to provide the desired hostname.